# 'Would ...was' vs 'Would ...is'

Tags: grammar

I am writing an email to someone to have a meeting over skype in the future. Which of the two sentences are correct?

Would you mind if the conversation ***was*** conducted over skype, as the reception is clearer?

vs

Would you mind if the conversation ***is*** conducted over skype, as the reception is clearer?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.  The correct question would be, Would you mind if the conversation **were** conducted over Skype?

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, the correct verb is *were*, a common use of the subjunctive mood.

Requests of the sort you are writing to your friend are generally made in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: Actually, the reason behind the subjunctive here is not due to the request, but rather due to the hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

@HalosGhost, I must respectfully disagree with you. Just because there is an *if* in the sentence doesn't make it a hypothetical. I am assuming that that is the reason you're calling it a hypothetical; please forgive me if I am wrong about that. The reason the sentence needs the subjunctive is that it is making a request. For example, you can easily change the wording to this:

Would you mind *that* the conversation *be* conducted over Skype as the reception is clearer?

Notice I have removed the *if*, replacing it with a *that* and changed the verb to the subjunctive *be*. This sentence is equivalent to the original, but no one would claim it's a hypothetical.

But even if one were to rearrange the sentence to make it into a hypothetical, he still wouldn't use the subjunctive here. The reason is that not only the statement must be a hypothetical, but also the writer must believe that the stated hypothetical is either impossible or extremely unlikely, neither of which seem to apply here.